# Why is my GCD method not responding?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Would anyone know why the `bmlabel` is not updated? and the log "score" shows nothing? Without GCD, it works fine, but it blocks the ui (i would like to show the numbers between 100 to 500 for example, showing 101, 102...499, 500 very fast, instead of going directly from "100" to "500"). So i wanted to use another thread to calculate it, even if i'm not sure it's the best way. Here's my code :

```
//in .h, i imported :
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


//in .m
@implementation ScoreLayer

-(void)updateScore:(int)num{
    CCLOG(@"hello");
    int newScore = score+num;
    //dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Test", 0);
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        for (int i=score; i< newScore; i++){
            score++;
            CCLOG(@"score:%i", score);
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];

            dispatch_async(main, ^{
                [bmlabel setString:str];
            });

        }
    });
    score = newScore;
}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        bmlabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"14763" fntFile:@"TestFont.fnt"];
        bmlabel.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0.5f);
        bmlabel.position = ccp(0,250.0f);
        [self addChild:bmlabel z:200]; 
            score = 14763;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't use cocos2d, but does setting the label automatically cause it to refresh, or do you need to send another message to make the on-screen version draw itself?

Comment: does `CCLOG(@"score:%i", score);` print correctly?

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your help! @gaige sorry i'm not sure to understand your question, i would like the text to be updated with score++ until i reach the newScore number (with setString in the "main" queue).

Comment: @Johnnywho no, nothing inside the GDC works... (?) but the code works if i don't use GDC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `score` property is a `__block` type because you're changing it inside block in line:

```
 score++;
```

because your block is executed with `dispatch_async` main loop continues execution and most likely encounters `score = newScore;` before your block even starts. When your block is about to run, `score` is already equal `newScore` and your loop's will never work, because its condition expression will return false. In:

```
for (int i=score; i< newScore; i++)
```

`i` will equal to `newScore` and because `newScore < newScore` is false, your loop will never run.

I suggest to delete last line in your `updateScore:` method.

```
score = newScore;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Johnnywho! it works fine now! so, how could i update "score" at the end? i tried to place score=newScore just after the for loop, in the queue, but it does not work : it goes to the right score, let's say 15 869, and then goes down to 15 327... ?

Comment: maybe try to use `dispatch_sync` instead `dispatch_async` in your second block. Just to be sure that loop is executed sequentially.

Comment: If that's not helping. Maybe your `updateScore:` method is called multiple times and that's the reason why score doesn't update sequentially. I'll suggest to create your queue outside method, because now you're creating new queue per method invocation and that could be a reason. Try to declare queue as `ivar` and create queue in `init` or somewhere else where it could be created just once, and then use your shared queue in `updateScore:`

Comment: thanks! actually, with "score++", score is updated as expected! so i don't need the line at the end, thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 2):

Your block is being executed asynchronously which means that the block executes in a new run loop ( = after you set `score` to `newScore`).